# How to write multivariate formula in python (patsy), does VAR support it?

Tags: python, regression, formula, patsy

I want to do multivariate data analysis using vector auto regression (`VAR`), but want more freedom. For example, the question I am dealing with can look like:

```
y1(t) = a11*y1(t-1) + a12*y1(t-2) + b11*y2(t-1)               + c11*x1(t) + c12*x2(t) + d1

y2(t) = a21*y1(t-1) +               b21*y2(t-1) + b22*y2(t-2) + c21*x1(t) + c22*x2(t) + d2
```

So you see, the above equations are not a simple `VAR(1)` or `VAR(2)` model, but a mix. Does python's any statistics model package supports such equations, and how to write it in formula or patsy?

Comment: by "Writing it in a formula" you mean just simply printing, formatting? if NO, I think you are doing some sort of iterative operation that each step is based on the previous step.

Comment: I need to generate a formula to feed to the VAR model, such as 
statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model.VAR.from_formula()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is the following approach can help?

```
y1=[0,0]
y2=[0,0]
x1=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
x2=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for t in range (2,11):
    tempY1 = y1[t-1] + y1[t-2] + y2[t-1]+ x1[t] + x2[t] + 1
    tempY2 = y1[t-1] + y2[t-1] + y2[t-2] +x1[t] + x2[t] + 1
    y1.append(tempY1)
    y2.append(tempY2)
```

Comment: I need to generate a formula to feed to the VAR model, such as 
statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.var_model.VAR.from_formula()